# How can you write Fermat's Last Theorem in a purely mathematical language?

Tags: logic

I'm fascinated by the way in which logic language is used to write propositions, and how different parts of a statement are chained together. I am personally interested in writing theorems in a purely mathematical form, with no words within them. How would this be applied to Fermat's Last Theorem?

Fermat's Last Theorem states that there are NO numbers $x, y, z$ that satisfy the equation $x^n+y^n=z^n$ for any integer $n\geq 3$.

How would you write that using only mathematical logical language?

Comment: Are you familiar with [logical quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic))?

Comment: Yes, at least at a basic level.  I am not familiar with the "chaining" of statements, though. Let me explain. The theorem states that "there are no x,y,z" that satisfy "the equation" for "n>2". There are pretty much three parts of the theorem (each one of the quoted parts). I just wanted to know how you would connect them

Comment: Please consider changing the title because pure mathematics and and the notation using logical symbols are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: $~\forall~ n\in Z^+:[n>2 \implies \neg \exists ~a,b,c \in Z^+:[a^n+b^n =c^n]]$

Comment: Does the ":" mean "such that"?. I've seen people using a "/", "|" or even just parentheses. What is the convention regarding this?

Comment: @JPPM  It's just punctuation that I find makes quantified statements more readable. I prefer the square brackets around logical expressions, and use parentheses for function and predicate arguments, ordered n-tuples and other algebraic expressions. This, too, makes logical expressions more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities:

$$\forall n\geq3,\;\forall a\geq1,\;\forall b\geq1,\;\forall c\geq1,\;a^n+b^n\ne c^n$$
$$\lnot\;\exists n\geq3,\;\exists a\geq1,\;\exists b\geq1,\;\exists c\geq1,\;a^n+b^n=c^n$$
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N,\;\forall a\in\mathbb N,\;\forall b\in\mathbb N,\;\forall c\in\mathbb N,\big(n\geq3\land abc\ne0\implies a^n+b^n\ne c^n\big)$$
$$\lnot\;\exists n\in\mathbb N,\;\exists a\in\mathbb N,\;\exists b\in\mathbb N,\;\exists c\in\mathbb N,\big(n\geq3\land abc\ne0\land a^n+b^n=c^n\big)$$